# Apply directive to input field using a click event

Tags: angular

I am trying to apply my keyboard directive using a method in my `TS file`. I have a button that has the method attached to it in which I call the directive but I do not see anything happening.

[I created a stackblitz for it.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/onscreen-keyboard-ztv1n1?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

**Here is my code as well:-**

**TS**

```
isKeyboardActive() {
  this.appOskInput;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div>
  <label>Name</label>
  <input appOskInput  />
</div>
<div>
  <label>Cell</label>
  <input appOskInput type="text" />
</div>

<button (click)="isKeyboardActive()">Enable</button>

<app-keyboard></app-keyboard>
```

Directive (separate file)

```
@Directive({
  selector: "[appOskInput]"
})
```

So basically when I click the `isKeyboardActive` button I want to append `appOskInput` to the first input field `Name`.

The reason why I want to do this is because the keyboard only opens when I click within the input field which is not a good user experience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First expose KeyboardService and ElementRef as public properties in directive

```
  public el:ElementRef;
  public keyboard:KeyboardService;

  constructor( _el: ElementRef,  _keyboard: KeyboardService) {
    this.el = _el;
    this.keyboard = _keyboard;
  }
```

Then inside component when you click button you can enable and disable keyboard as per your requirement.

```
isKeyboardActive() {  
    this.appOskInput.first.keyboard.fireKeyboardRequested(true);
    this.appOskInput.first.el.nativeElement.focus();
  }
```

**[Forked Working Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/onscreen-keyboard-py6hgc?file=src/app/app.component.ts)**